# loop through and remove form elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have been writing a Javascript quiz whilst learning Javascript, but have encountered a problem.

I have one function that dynamically creates the question/answers with radio buttons to mark off the questions.

When I use this second function to attempt to remove the question/answers so I can show the new ones; it removes the text (in p tags) but doesn't remove the radio buttons, even though they also show as children to the form element.

```js
function removeLastQuestions() {
    
    var allQuestions = document.getElementById('questionForm');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.children.length; i++) {
        allQuestions.removeChild(allQuestions.children[i]);
    }
}
```

The question/answers and buttons are contained within a form with the id of "questionForm"

I guess I could put the whole form within a div and remove the form, but I'm wondering why looping over them isn't working. I'm trying to do it without using Jquery.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add the corresponding html source to your post. You can do it by using the "edit" link underneath your question.

Comment: The html is pretty sparse before the other function generates form but I'll put it in,  though I have a working solution now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var node = document.getElementById('questionForm');

while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}
```

This will remove all form elements.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/x3mymwra/)</kbd>